# Using Apply with LinkedIn to Register User

Tags: php, linkedin-api

In one of my projects, I need to use the full user profile at the registration. It's been working great for me but after the 12th of May, I will need to use the "Apply with LinkedIn" to get the full profile.
My application does not fulfill the "Apply with LinkedIn" requirements. Therefore, I wanted to ask if I can use the "Apply with LinkedIn" to register a user on my system. Is there any chance of possibility? If yes, then what are the requirements for me to get an access from the LinkedIn and if no, what are my options to do so?
I have checked and I need permission to crawl for user information from the user's public profile as well.

Comment: Check the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822738/want-to-fetch-data-of-user-using-id-in-linkedin-using-rest-api/29841052?noredirect=1#comment47808543_29841052

Comment: The solution is still going to use the basic profile as a default option. I need to fetch the user job history during the user registration process. As you can see that I don't fulfill the requirement of "Apply with LinkedIn" here. I have submitted a request and am yet to hear about it.

Comment: If your app fails review, try for LinkedIn Partner program : https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Comment: have you tried either of the programs yourself?